# Is it worth enrolling in a Ph.D. program without employment?

Tags: phd

As I understand, European universities offer two types of Ph.D. programs:

1. Ph.D. [without employment](https://doktorat.univie.ac.at/en/doctoralphd-programmes/natural-sciences/admission/)
2. [Ph.D. with employment](https://forschung.univie.ac.at/en/services/funding/early-career-researchers/unidocs-fellowship-programme/)

As far as I understand, North American universities do not work in that way.

Is it worth enrolling in a Ph.D. program without employment (#1) careerwise if someone wants a job in academia in future?

Comment: In several French universities you practically cannot enroll on a PhD on computer science without an employment contract (e.g. [CIFRE](https://www.enseignementsup-recherche.gouv.fr/cid22130/les-cifre.html))

Comment: The question in the title and the question in the post are wildly different. What are you asking, exactly?

Comment: Being in a PhD program with work contract does not mean that you will teach. Your working obligations may be exclusively research related.

Comment: As is this question is extremely unclear. Can you focus on what exactly it is you would like us to answer?

Comment: Even in the U.S., Ph.D. study in many subjects is without employment.  Most subjects in the arts and the humanities, for example.

Answer (score 7):

Europe is not a country but a continent. The links you gave are from the university of Vienna, and the example of employed PhD students refers to a special program from the University of Vienna, so that is not even Austria-wide.

Enrolling in a PhD program without employment can mean many things, for example it could mean you get no financial support what so ever, i.e. you are self-funded (but even there is variability depending on how much tuition you pay). Being in a PhD program without employment could also mean you receive a stipend instead of wage (which has consequences for your eligibility for social security, pension, health insurgence, etc. This varies to a huge extend from country to country).

In general a PhD degree is a PhD degree regardless of how it was funded. It may be that some programs are more prestigious than others, but that is country specific: It may be that in some countries particular stipends are very prestigious, while in other countries employment is so rare, that getting it is considered prestigious.

I would be weary of self-funded PhD programs, but otherwise stipends and employment contracts are both fine.

Comment: +1 for "Europe is not a country". I do not know how often one must say this on Academia.SE.